# Android ASCII Emoticons and PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, ascii

I have an app for Android, iOS and Windows Phone that has a chat. I created the PHP web service that serves the app. I searched on Google and here, but I didn't find a solution.

[image: Android's Keyboard]

I'm trying to use Android's native keyboard emoticons in my chat. Every time I insert an emoticon, an ASCII special char is used to represent it. I use `htmlentities($char)` to escape the special chars, save them in MySQL, use `html_entity_decode($char)` to decode and return as a JSON response.

The problem is: some emoticons can be encoded, others can't be. For example, the first smile of the image above is represented by the char `☺` and its code is `&#9786;`. But I can't get the angel's smile code, `htmlentities($char)` returns an empty string.

I tried an online [ASCII Code Tool](http://slayeroffice.com/tools/ascii/) with my Android and I got the code `55357` for the angel emoticon. Then I tried to insert the code `&#55357;` directly in MySQL, but `html_entity_decode($char)` returns the same string, without decode. Finally, I created a HTML page with the `&#55357;` char, but both browsers, Android and Desktop, display an unknown char `�`.

Any idea what is happening? Am I doing the right way?

Comment: they're non-standard characters, and htmlentities() only deals with the "standard" chars that are defined in the html specs.

Comment: So, how can I store the in MySQL? MySQL can't deal with them too. HTML Encode/Decode was an option.

Comment: base64 might be a more appropriate type to store the data in

Comment: Well, should I encode base64 to store them and decode base64 after retrieve them?

Comment: mysql couldn't care less that they're entities. if you use a `blob`-type field, mysql will just be a storage system. stuff in some "binary" text, retrieve it, and mysql won't change a thing. no need for encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace them in your Android App with the Codes so PHP doesn't need handle them.